# Use JQuery Odd selector for separate ul tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a JQuery snippet to add class names for li tags with odd indexes.

```
<div class="test">

  <ul class="list1">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list2">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

This is the JQuery snippet.

```
$('.test li:odd').addClass('red');
```

This snippet adds 'red' class to 1st, 3rd, 5th li tags of 'list1' and **2nd, 4th li tags of 'list2'** (Because it takes all the li tags as a single list and then select odd indexes)

But I want the odd indexes of list1 and list2 separately (1st, 3rd, 5th li tags of 'list1' and **1st, 3rd li tags of 'list2'**)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you displaying data statically or dynamically ( using any loop ) ?

Comment: @Priyank dynamically.

Comment: give me your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(odd)` pseudo-class instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.test li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">

  <ul class="list1">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list2">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
  </ul>

</div>
<button type="button">Press me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `:odd` selector counts the element's order in the document. Basically, the order in `$(selector)`:

> Selected elements are in the order of **their appearance in the document**. ([source](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/))

You'll need to use [`nth-child(odd)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child), instead.

```js
$('.test li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('red');
$('.test li:odd').addClass('underline');
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

.underline{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <ul class="list1">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or just avoid using JS altogether:

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul class="list1">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternative; you could easily do this without JavaScript

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <ul class="list1">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list2">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```